# mysql PPA - invalid signature

Tags: apt, mysql, ppa, gnupg

I already have `mysql-server` package installed!!!

I want to make sure I have the most recent MySQL in my Ubuntu. So (long time ago) I added `repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu` PPA. Recently I noticed errors related to this repository when doing `apt update`. Following [this guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-gpg-signature.html) I've downloaded and imported public GPG key.

Now when I do `sudo apt update` I get this error:

```
Err:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
```

OS information: Ubuntu 18.10

Should I worry about this invalid signature? How to fix the error?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The error you are seeing indicates that your key is expired.

You can list all keys on your system with the command `sudo apt-key list` if you wish to narrow the output you can always pipe the output through `grep expired` to obtain just a list of the expired keys.

For each expired key, issue the command `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver [KEY_SERVER] --recv-keys [KEY]` where [KEY] is related to the number in question or in this case:

8C718D3B5072E1F5

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5`
keyserver.ubuntu.com refers to an open PGP keyserver run by Canonical, Ltd.

You can also search for the key via web interface at [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/)

where you'll get a page similar but not identical to  this:

[image]

Entering the key from the EXPKEYSIG preceded by 0x in the search box and searching should return results similar to this:

[image]

To the best of my knowledge the 8 hex digits is the short version (public key) you need to obtain an updated key with the command

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5072E1F5`

Sources:

- https://linux-audit.com/how-to-solve-an-expired-key-keyexpired-with-apt/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768657/cannot-add-keys-from-keys-gnupg-net

Comment: I supposed to do all these in Ansible playbook. Any idea?

Comment: @SenG Perhaps you find this useful. https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-playbook-example/

Comment: Looks like **keys.gnupg.net** from the answer isn't available anymore. I tried to use https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/ and it worked.

Comment: @maksadbek Nice catch!  I'll edit.

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <expired-key>` command works for me. Great! Thanks

Comment: It didn't work for me.
`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29`
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.eEd2EYwMwm/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Comment: It's worked for a lot of people, I suggest that you open a new question, citing this one to provide context

Answer (score 21):

Get the latest (not expired) MySQL APT repository from:
  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Currently:
https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks, using latest version of repository file works perfectly.

Comment: This fixed it; unfortunately Oracle doesn't seem to offer a "latest" deb url, meaning that if you are installing this programmatically in a script, you have to manually update the hardcoded file url once a year or so.

Answer (score 3):

try running 
`$sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5072E1F5`

source:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85029

Comment: The keyserver looks suspicious. I don't see `keys.gnupg.net` mention in the linked page. Could you provide more details in your answer?

Comment: Its a public key server. find it on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-gpg-signature.html

Answer (score 3):

Instruction for apt.

1. download key

   A. from mysql website https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-gpg-signature.html

   B. or from public repo `shell> gpg --recv-keys 5072E1F5`
2. `shell> gpg --import mysql_pubkey.asc`
3. `shell> sudo apt-key add mysql_pubkey.asc`

Comment: See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141364/225694) for a process that works to resolve expired keys regardless of package.

Comment: none of the answers had "sudo apt-key add <file>" step.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The GPG public key is not correct here. Need to install latest GPG public key again.

Please try

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
```

It will install correct MySQL-server GPG key on server then add repo of mysql server

For Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy)

```
# echo "deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-cluster-8.0
deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql-8.0.list
```

For Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):

```
# echo "deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ focal mysql-apt-config
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ focal mysql-8.0
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ focal mysql-tools
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ focal mysql-cluster-8.0
deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ focal mysql-8.0" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql-8.0.list
```

For Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic):

```
# echo "deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-cluster-8.0
deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql-8.0.list
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial):

```
# echo "deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-apt-config
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-8.0
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-tools
deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-cluster-8.0
deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-8.0" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql-8.0.list
```

Then run

```
# apt update
# apt install mysql-server
```