# Cannot upgrade to MySQL 8 from 5.7

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, mysql

I'm trying to update `MySQL` to the latest version, actually I have the version 5.7, what I did is the following:

*1. Downloaded the package*:

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

then I choosed this:

[image]

later I seelcted MySQL 8.0 and finally this:

[image]

*2.Update*

Then I run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

*3. Version Checking*:

So I checked the current version using `apt policy mysql-server`

and this return:

[image]

These are some logs during the update:

[image]

What I did wrong?

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`?

Comment: @Kulfy I added the output at the bottom of the question

Comment: This question [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120363/mysql-ppa-invalid-signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120363/mysql-ppa-invalid-signature) discusses fixing the same problem, from the same repo