# No answer for ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' in Ubuntu 16.04 in askubuntu.com

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python

I ran the following :

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-8.0"

sudo: unable to resolve host root
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

To solve this I took numerous chances as said in askubuntu.com

```
sudo apt-get install python-apt
sudo: unable to resolve host root
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-apt is already the newest version (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gksu libgksu2-0 pencil2d snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 393 not upgraded.


~$ sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall
sudo: unable to resolve host root
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gksu libgksu2-0 pencil2d snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 393 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/147 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 208998 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9_i386.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9) over (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9) ...
Setting up python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9) ...


$ sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': File exists


$ sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
cp: cannot stat 'apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gksu libgksu2-0 pencil2d snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 393 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/147 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 208998 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9_i386.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9) over (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9) ...
Setting up python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.9) ...

$ sudo update-alternatives  --set python3  /usr/bin/python3.7
```

I tried each of these commands separately. Still I got :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-8.0"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

### To be frank I am fed up with this error and I'm sure that none of the above commands and commands given in other questions of askubuntu.com didn't answer my need. As a last hope, I posted this question. Please Answer me.

#### I'm very very sad that AskUbuntu.com is unable to solve my issue

EDIT :
I have the following in my dist-packages :

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I use this command :

```
$ sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
cp: cannot stat 'apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you do anything relevant before this error occured (e.g. mess with your python installation)?

Comment: No. I installed using : ```sudo apt install python3```  My python3 version is 3.7.9

Comment: And I have python 2.7 already installed in my ubuntu. Then, I separately installed python 3.5 for IDLE. But in my terminal, onlu 3.7.9 and 2.7 works. What to do @danzel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following simple and old procedure.

cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

sudo cp --remove-destination apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so

For more details click the following link.

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt_pkg-error/

Comment: It results : ```cp: cannot stat 'apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory```

Comment: What to do next @cr4zyc0der?

Comment: Check my edits please

Comment: $ sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
cp: not writing through dangling symlink 'apt_pkg.so'

Comment: sudo cp --remove-destination apt_pkg.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so  i said this , adding --remove-destination might help, before posting qn search properly, this is an old issue as i mentioned before

Comment: I did. But still that file exists in my directory

Comment: that file should exist , now try installing mysql P.S (did the command work with --remove-destination?)

Comment: full marks to you. also bounty. really thanks